# Will session.invalidate() remove the attribute set to the session?

Tags: jsp, servlets

If I set the attribute value in the request and after that I call `session.invalidate()`, what will happen to attribute values? Will they be there still?

Answer (score 8):

They will be still in memory, but they are not referenced by the `HttpSession` in question anymore. I.e. they are *not accessible* by `HttpSession` anymore.

Once the Garbage Collector runs and those objects do not have any other references by any other classes/instances, then they will ultimately be destroyed and free memory.

Answer (score 2):

request and sessions are two different things. attributes set in request will be available until you serve the request. Once done all values will be vanished.

Attributes in session will be there until session gets expired or you call invalidate explicitly. Either of these will kill the current session and create a new one on next request onwards.

Comment: Okay thank you.Please also let me know Sesssion object will be having the following things right session id,Hashcode,valid session or not.. if we call session.invalidate() will it makes the session as null or just will change the valid session flag to false?Thanks much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: session.invalidate() will clear everything in your session. Nothing will be left over. From the next request you will be provided with new session object which will be having a different id. session.isNew() method will returns "true" if the client does not yet know about the session or if the client chooses not to join the session